# How to set first few pages in thesis (report class) as one sided?

Tags: pdftex, geometry

First 7 pages of my thesis needed to be printed on odd pages and one-sided. My `report` class is set as two sided. How do I change this?

I had earlier seen in another post a way to change it to two side: `\newgeometry{twoside}` and to restore back to one side: `\restoregeometry`. But passing argument as `oneside` is not working.

How do I go about this?

Comment: can't you just use `\cleardoublepage` after each page?

Comment: I had inserted \newpage. But I was wondering if there was more neat method.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` is more natural than `\newpage` as it is designed to get to the next odd page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the solution. If you could post it, I could up vote it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\cleardoublepage` is designed for this use, it is designed to force the following content to the next odd numbered page.